# BitLocker Drive Encryption Recovery Error: Error Recovering Disk

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, data-recovery, bitlocker, decryption

I have this external HD which holds Photos of my whole life, Video Tutorials and Ebooks. It has two partitions (H: and I:) and both partitions were Bit Locker Encrypted. I have recently moved to Mac (with Bootcamp) and I decided to Decrypt / Remove the Bit Locker as otherwise the HD wasn't accessible on Mac Side. So I started with decryption (on Windows 10) of 1st. partition (H:) and it was just a few percent done when my little daughter disturbed the wire which caused decryption to stop and not complete.

Now, I am unable to access the drive by any mean. It doesn't ask for the Password and it just shows one drive (I think the one which I was decrypting). To make it worse, the recovery key backup was in the drive itself and I don’t have any other backup. However, I remember the password which I was using to unlock the Drive.

Also, there is an anomaly to this behavior too. On Windows 10 which is having updates on, I can only see one drive/partition (no Lock pad) and it's always busy. The system stops responding if I double click the drive. However, on Windows 7 which is actually an old OS to Windows 10 surprisingly, I can see both Drives/Partitions with a Lock pad.

And the one which I started decrypting is not accessible and throws an error: Error recovering disk: "A recovery key was not found on this drive. the drive can not be unlocked" while the one which was yet to be decrypted is accessible. Please help me gain access to the partition which is not accessible. I have read about this Windows BitLocker Repair Tool but since I don’t have a Recovery Key or Recovery Password I can’t use it.

I just have the normal password which I was using to Open the Drive. Another utility that I tried is from m3datarecovery.com and that is accepting the password but not able to recover the data. Any solution to fix the drive and get the data back. Can we make the Drive Decryption resume may be through Windows Restore or Any other Utility / Events viewer etc. Or get the Meta Data and find recovery key/password using normal password. May be I am thinking high.

Here's a screenshot of error from Windows 7 ([original file](https://prnt.sc/ugdtk0)):

[image]

Edit:

1. Disturbed the wire means... Tremble of USB connector. The HD don't require external power connection.
2. The Decryption was just 10 - 15% complete and the connection get lost.
3. The disk was originall encrypted using Windows 7 BitLocker.

Comment: If you encrypted the drive on a Windows 10 machine then there is a very good chance you used a encryption schema that is incompatible with Windows 7.  Unfortunately, the events you describe, point to permanent data loss.

Answer (score 0):

## Stop right there

**Anything you do from now on decreases chances of successful data recovery.**

Contact a professional data recovery company, describe what happened with as many details as possible and let them do their job. It will be very expensive and success is not guaranteed. Data recovery on regular volumes is expensive. Encryption makes things much harder and it's possible that you won't be able to get anything back.

Start making backups. They're much cheaper than data recovery and if done properly, should give 100% chance of recovery in case of accident like this.

Answer (score 0):

"disturb the wire" is not a precise description. It can make a big difference if your daughter cut the power supply, the interface cable or both.

Disclaimer: I have no practical experience with Bitlocker!

The solution is beyond your and my scope. You need professional assistance without any guarantee of success.

Some basics:
The key you have is not the key to decrypt the data. Your key provides access to a kind of real key which can be stored in different locations.

The first thing is to find out why Bitlocker went into recovery mode.
Your "wire disturbance" may have been a trigger as listed here:
https://specopssoft.com/blog/what-causes-bitlocker-recovery-mode/

In such a case where your real key has not been overwritten, the trigger might be reset. If that fails, you need the recovery key.

I see a very small chance left that the recovery key stored as a text file you wrote onto your H:-partition can be read out. Your text file with the recovery key is very short. It fits completely into a thing called "MFT entry". It does not need additional storage called "clusters". If, by chance, your file is located in a part of the MFT that has already been decrypted, a specialist should be able to read it out.

Furthermore, the file that has to be searched for has a small fixed length. You could even determine that length by encrypting any other volume, saving the recovery key as a file and looking up the length. Compared to the big length of your pictures, ebooks and videos this file will most probably have a unique short length.
This is an additional piece of information for automatic searches.

Please doublecheck if you did not write your recovery key file onto the other partition!

Another thing to consider: Did you encrypt an empty H:-partition and put in your recovery key file first or did you you encrypt an already filled up partition?

This gives an indication where in the MFT your recovery key file may be located.

13.9.2020 23:33 MESZ Addendum:
The ability of third party software to recognize a Bitlocker recovery key as wrong does not necessary rely on the ability to readout volume information.

Proof:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secprov/protectkeywithnumericalpassword-win32-encryptablevolume

[...The numerical password must contain 48 digits. These digits can be divided into 8 groups of 6 digits, with the last digit in each group indicating a checksum value for the group. Each group of 6 digits must be divisible by 11 and must be less than 720896. Assuming a group of six digits is labeled as x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, and x6, the checksum x6 digit is calculated as –x1+x2–x3+x4–x5 mod 11...]

13.9.2020 23:27 MESZ Addendum:

Sheryl, use Veracrypt and drop Bitlocker! You can extract the Veracrypt header file and store it anywhere as its possession is not sufficient for decryption.
The on-disc file format is well documented in the PDF manual.

What I learnt from your experience is:
Never decrypt a drive oder volume. Extract its content to another drive!
Right now I could not even say how my beloved Truecrypt would have reacted in your case.

Comment: Hello... Thanks for your answer! Being a software developer I do understand how encryption works and your anwser makes much sense to me. When I say disturbed the wire then it means shaking/tremble of USB wire. It's an external hard drive powered by USB itself and don't required an additional power source. The disk was just 10 - 15% decrypted. The Partitions were encrypted using Windows 7. I encrypted the drive when it was just having a few MB of data and then I transferred all years of Photos and Tuts to it. Also, I moved the key backups along with other sensitive files to that partition!

Comment: One thing worth considering is: I do have the pasword and software from M3Datarecovery is accepting it, if I enter wrong password... The software from M3 (which wasn't able to help much) shows it wrong. Which means the drive still able to verify the password but being able to recreate the interface to request the password is the problem.

Comment: Sheryl, I am sorry, you are very likely wrong in your assumption which is a good point. Took me some time to google a valid source for the proof. I update my response now.

Comment: @r2d3 I don't think the drive is in recovery mode. As far as I understand (but I'm not sure since I couldn't find more the two or three relevant pages on how bitlocker works in my quick search) the key gets stored in bitlocker metadata (as you correctly point out - then the password is used to retrieve the key, at least that's what I assume). So if the part of the metadata containing the decryption key is corrupted it can not be recovered anymore, which seems to be the case here but again I'm not sure. Good idea trying to recover the key-backup from the partially decrypted files.

Comment: r2d3 and @Albin Thanks for more insights on this. At this stage I really don't know what to do so I am not doing anything on the HD. This is a good lesson and I realized that you should always have more than one backup of your data (but keeping everyting in sync and avoiding data redundency is a problem). Also may be HDs are not a good medium to save life critical data like this.

Comment: @Sheryl I'm curious, what do you mean by "avoiding data redundancy is a problem"? A Backup is the very definition of data redundancy?!

Answer (score -1):

**Stop** what you are doing and disconnect the drive physically. And **BEFORE** you do anything else, make a "1:1 backup" of the drive to another drive (clone) or an image file. The saying goes "no backup no mercy" which (unfortunately) you are experiencing now.

Unfortunately I don't have a "real" solution just some insight/advise:

For this kind of problem most likely there will be no standard way of recovery (especially no automatic one). In order to solve this it might be necessary to analyse what **exactly** happened, how far the decryption progressed etc. and what other problems might have occurred from the "disturbed wire". For this it's necessary to understand how the Bitlocker decryption process works (not the "decryption" itself, but the changes made to the volume during the process, what data gets decrypted first, how the decrypted data gets stored etc.). Also some general knowledge about data recovery will be necessary otherwise it's likely you make things worse (which can be fatal if you don't backup before you start the recovery on the original media).

I would recommend you either

- read up and get some fundamental knowledge on data recovery and Bitlocker first (which unfortunately will be time consuming)
- or get a a professional data recovery service (which unfortunately will be money consuming and usually there are no guarantees).

Hopefully I'm wrong and someone knows Bitlocker better then I do and knows a standard approach.

PS. Note that it might be impossible to decrypt the data e.g. if Bitlocker's metadata got corrupted ([source](https://www.m3datarecovery.com/bitlocker-drive-data-recovery/bitlocker-not-asking-for-password.html)).

PPS. I would also recommend to get a bigger "software" partition/drive. 4.25% free disk space is a little low.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what's wrong with this post and how it should be improved. Downvoting without explanation is counter-productive.

Comment: I was not the original voter, but thus post provides no useful in site, and could be wring if the key is in memory.

Comment: gronostaj, I downvoted your post because your advice is not specific and the following quote from you sums up into: "Try to learn about the problem to solve it":
>You need to analyse what exactly happened, how far the decryption progressed etc. and what other problems might have occurred from the "disturbed wire". For this you need to understand how the decryption works. It doesn't look like you have the proper knowledge to recover the data and it's likely you make things worse (which is fatal without a backup).

I would recommend you either read up and get some fundamental knowledge first

Comment: Sheryl's description is specific enough to give specific advice. Details about the encryption algorithm are not needed. It is rather how the the on-disc volume format differs from an unencrypted partition and where the storage location of the genuine key is.

Comment: @gronostaj I was wondering that myself, since in essence, I don't say anything else then the other two answers: go to a professional. Except maybe for r2d3's idea/guess to recover it from the decrypted files (assuming they are accessible at all with a partial decryption).

Comment: Albin, the difference is that you did not state "Go, learn encryption". If I had asked the question I would have been very angry to be told that I should learn about encryption instead of being given an answer.

Comment: @r2d3 Thanks for your insight. I wasn't talking about the "encryption algorithm" nor was I talking about how data gets de- or encrypted. I was talking about the "decryption process" (the changes made to the volume during the process, what data gets decrypted first, how the decrypted data gets stored etc.) - I apparently wrongly though that is obvious. All sorts of things "can happen" ones the decryption starts it all depends on how it was implemented. As long as this is unknown everything about the recovery is just a guess (which sometimes is successful and sometimes it isn't).

Comment: @r2d3 "the difference is that you did not state "Go, learn encryption". - not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my primary language. You basically did not say that Sheryl should solve her problem herself by learning about encryption as opposed to what gronostaj said.

Comment: @r2d3 NP, still don't really understand what you mean, but I think we misunderstand each other or rather my answer. I meant **if** she wants to solve the problem herself **then** she needs to learn about Bitlocker's "decryption process" (see my other comment) and some basic recovery skills like backing up before you recover (there are plenty of answered questions about that, no need to repeat it again). This is - of course - assuming there isn't a standard way but since recovery software doesn't work I doubt there is one. But I think everything is said now at least from my side.

Comment: @Albin I was in a little bit discomfort after reading your comment about my ability but that's not a concern as I want people to answer and enjoy this community.

Comment: Btw, I just took a backup of other partition which is still BitLocker Encrypted but accessible normally on Windows 7 (don't showup on Windows 10). Also, I have written to MS and Segate about my problem. I will update here once I hear anything from them. Thanks for your answers guys!

Comment: @Sheryl sorry, you took it personal, it wasn't meant that way. Thanks for the feedback I keep that in mind next time. I changed the wording a bit, hopefully it's not as discomforting any more.